# Replace substituted characters in file paths strings from XML file in Python 3?

Tags: string, python-3.10

I'm reading file paths from an XML file with Python and they `print` with substituted characters:

> file:///Volumes/Storage/Music/Media/Bjo%CC%88rk/Post/02%20Hyperballad.m4a

I'm guessing this has to do with their encoding that's maybe not UTF-8?
Is there an easy way to get a cleaned up string, like this:

> file:///Volumes/Storage/Music/Media/Björk/Post/02 Hyperballad.m4a

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib.parse.unquote()` did the trick.